# Travis CI Build doesn't install gems for JRuby platform

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems, travis-ci

I have a travis build set up for my project that also run on JRuby. I mention the `activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter` gem in the `Gemfile` for the `:jruby` platform:

```
platforms :jruby do
  gem "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter"
end
```

but the build still always fails with the message `LoadError: Please install the sqlite3 adapter:`gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter`(sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)` and the gem actually doesn't get installed.

The project is open source at https://github.com/simplabs/rails_api_auth, the build is at https://travis-ci.org/simplabs/rails_api_auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On travis-ci for sqlite3 the [docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#SQLite3) seem to indicate you need 'jdbc-sqlite3:

```
platforms: jruby do
  gem 'jdbc-sqlite3'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
end
```

**EDIT**

Actually I think your real problem is that you checked-in your Gemfile lock files (Gemfile.lock && gemfiles/*.lock).  Travis-ci isn't re-evaluating what Gems are needed for the particular platforms.

Answer (score -1):

what happens if you do?:

```
platforms :jruby do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
end
```

maybe the adapter is still relying on classes from the sqlite3 gem (thats what i read from the errors so far)

Comment: Installing the sqlite3 gem doesn't work at all with JRuby: https://travis-ci.org/simplabs/rails_api_auth/jobs/72986143